# Should this hardware piece look like this?

Tags: mac, hardware, repair

In the image you can see the hardware part of the battery (I think) and it looks weird with all the white things. Is this normal, because the Mac was recently bought. This is a MacBook Air 2019.

Would be interesting to know what this is.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Added an image with circles to see the white things I am talking about. Also on those "bloated" metal things is some thin white layer, seems like the same thing like the other white stuff.

Comment: Add more specific info - mac model, serial no, year, etc

Comment: Can you draw colored lines around or pointing to the white things? I only see silver solder and two white rings with the fan assembly

Comment: @JohnKeates: I updated the post with a new image.

Comment: If it looks dusty or chalky and you can scratch it with a piece of soft plastic, and then it turns powdery it could be an indication of liquid reaction. In other cases it is simply a result of the reflow process, probably just soldering flux from the paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks normal.

- The circular white spots are moisture indicators, which turn red on contact with water. This is to inform a technician if the logic board has been in contact with water to possibly decline warranty cover for repairs.
- The ‘white dust’ on the edges are part of the production process.

Comment: I ask because this notebook got water damage and I opened it very quickly to drain the excess water. But I am not sure if these things in the picture are already the cause of the water or just normal and would look the same even without a water damage.